# Rename the zonal statics table same as the raster name in ArcGIS model builder

Tags: raster, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.4, zonal-statistics

I need to get zonal statics for multiple raster files. However, I would like the name of the output table to be the same as the raster name but i am getting errors.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which software are you working with? Please add a fitting tag.

Comment: Maybe you cant name a table `*.tif`. Use [Parse path](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/parse-path.htm) to extract filename without the extension

Comment: Working with ArcGIS 10.4

Comment: any spaces in your path ?

Comment: No spaces in path